# setSoTimeout not working in java tcp connection

Tags: java

I have a server that connects with a client to receive a string, but when the connection is lost the server stays to the same condition and doesn't go back to the state in which it tries to make a connection again. I used `setSoTimeout` but it isn't working.

Here is my code :

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
                Socket connectionSocket = null;
                BufferedOutputStream outToClient = null;

                try {
                    System.out.println("connecting to send "+fileToSend);

                    welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3249);
                    connectionSocket  = welcomeSocket.accept();



                    connectionSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                    welcomeSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                    outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("set so");
                    break;
                    // Do exception handling
                }
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not throwing the exception?

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually make a `read` call on clients input stream in order for the SO timeout to be triggered. And the exception will only be triggered if said `read` call blocks for longer than the timeout setting.

Also, its useless to set an SO timeout on the server socket, as you will never be 'reading' from it on the server side.

Comment: You can use any read method on the client sockets input stream, for example `connectionSocket.getInputStream().read()`. See the [Javadoc for InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) for other options.

Comment: @EJP - its useless in the context of what the OP is trying to do (reset the clients already established connection, if the connection has been dropped on the client side).

Comment: Then that is what your answer should say. At present it is wrong.